# MacOs: Correct location for data files

Tags: macos, qt5

I'm a Windows developer finally getting my feet wet on Mac - I've already stumbled across translocation.

I have a Qt-based application that I am porting to Mac and have a few basic types of user data. The app is distributed currently via zip file

1) Settings/config data. I understand this belongs in a plist file

2) XML-based application data. This data is intended to be edited by both users and the application. In most cases, it will only be power users that manually edit these files.

3) Image-based (jpg/png) in-application icons. This data is used by the application and expected to be created/provided separately by users.

On Windows, both 2 and 3 are simply located in subdirectories of the .exe.

What are the options or "correct" locations for such application data?

Answer (score 1):

The usual location is a custom folder in the `Application Support` directory. This directory exists in the local domain (`/Library/Application Support/`) to save data for all users and in the user domain (`~/Library/Application Support/`) to save data per user.

There is a convention to name the custom folder in `Application Support` with the bundle identifier of the application but this is not mandatory.

While the `Application Support` directory is created implicitly your app is responsible to create the custom folder.

`(NS)FileManager` provides an API to get the `Application Support` directory without hard-coding paths. If your app is sandboxed you must use this `(NS)FileManager` API anyway

Comment: Thanks - this sounds reasonable. Is it common practice for an application to bring a default data file and copy it to the Application Support directory for further use?

Comment: Yes, that’s common practice.